# How to draw a line in a canvas which extends part of its parent and be relative to its parent

Tags: wpf, canvas, drawing, line

I have a canvas on a wpf page.

The code is as follow:

```
<Canvas>

    <Line Stroke="red" X1="100" Y1="125" X2="1000" Y2="125"  />
</Canvas>
```

It is in a specific place, but  want its place be relative to its parent, so if the parent resized, its position changes too.

How can I do this?

Comment: i'm not sure i understand.... if the Canvas is the content or Child of any FrameworkElement, it will get moved when its parents gets moved, so just including the Canvas in the right place seems ok or ... ???

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Viewbox>
    <Canvas Height="700" Width="1300">
        <Line Stroke="red" X1="100" Y1="125" X2="1000" Y2="125"  />
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

use height and width for canvas as per ur requirement and u can set stretch and strechdirection property of viewbox

Comment: But I want that canvas is also stretched.